# Remove button like appearence from headers of QTableView with style sheet

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtableview

I have a table view that looks like this

[image]

Is there any way that I can remove the borders around the headers and make them look plain?

My current style sheet for the table is:

```
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.102273, y1:0.068, x2:0.392318, y2:0.614, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

Comment: consider selecting the answer correct or adding a new one with the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, headers are "stylable". Just notice that headers are inside the `QTableView` but are different widgets (They are `QHeaderView`). What you need to change is the style for the `sections` of the `QHeaderView` so you just have to select it correctly in your style sheet.

Following a very basic example so you can have a starting point.

This is what I would set as style sheet of the `QTableWidget` in order to achieve what you want:

```
QTableView {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.102273, y1:0.068, x2:0.392318, y2:0.614, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
}

QHeaderView::section {
    border: 0px;
}
```

More info on styling `QHeaderView`s can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview).

I hope this helps.